# How to use lapply to create reactive objects in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, lapply

I currently have a Shiny code that requires several different reactive datasets but that are sequentially generated to the point where I think using `lapply` would make more sense as the number of datasets increases.

```
repFunction1 <- reactive({
    iris$Species[1]
)}

repFunction2 <- reactive({
    iris$Species[2]
)}

repFunction3 <- reactive({
    iris$Species[3]
)}
```

My attempts at replicating this with `lapply` is as follows:

```
lapply(1:3, function(i){
    paste0('repFunction', i) <- reactive({
      iris$Species[i]
    })
})

#Both above and below don't work

lapply(1:3, function(i){
    assign(paste0('repFunction', i), reactive({
      iris$Species[i]
    })
  )
})
```

Since both of these don't work, is there any way to do this without having to repeat the same code over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
lapply(1:3, function(i) {
  output[[ paste0("repFunction", i) ]] <- reactive({
    iris$Species[i]
  })
})
```

Comment: But that creates an output object that can't be called inside other outputs. Your example creates `output$repFunction1` instead of `repFunction1()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the reactive conductors in a list:

```
reactives <- lapply(1:3, function(i){
  reactive({
    iris$Species[i]
  })
})
names(reactives) <- paste0('repFunction', 1:3)
```

Then call the first one by doing `reactives[["repFunction1"]]` or `reactives[[1]]`.